# Getting Unexpected result in using min(key)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am having two tables ss_test and ss_ceastore_config ss_test has field called store_id which maps to ss_ceastore_config id.
my ss_test contains servers entry which tells that which store it is using 
so i am trying to find which store is used min times and its id. 
i have below query written.

```
 select id,
        min(server_counts) as server_counts,
        isalive 
 from (select ss_ceastore_config.id ,
              count(server_id)as server_counts, 
               ss_ceastore_config.isalive 
       from ss_test 
       right join ss_ceastore_config 
       on ss_test.store_id = ss_ceastore_config.id 
       group by store_id 
       order by id) join_1
```

my inner query gives me proper result as below

```
id Ascending    server_counts   isalive
1                 5               1
2                 0               1
```

so i want to select below record from inner query output using min function

```
id Ascending    server_counts   isalive
2                 0               1
```

but it gives unexpected result with my outer query as below

```
id  server_counts   isalive
1         0            1
```

why this so? why it is giving id 1 for server_counts 0?
how to fix this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id,
    server_counts,
    isalive 
from (select ss_ceastore_config.id ,
          count(server_id)as server_counts, 
           ss_ceastore_config.isalive 
   from ss_test 
   right join ss_ceastore_config 
   on ss_test.store_id = ss_ceastore_config.id 
   group by store_id 
   order by id) join_1
order by server_counts asc
limit 1;
```

Your original query was not working because you were doing an aggregate `SELECT` using the `MIN()` function along with non-aggregate columns such as `id` and `isalive`.  I believe that MySQL makes no guarantee about *which* `id` value it will return along with the minimum for that column.

My strategy is to return *all* rows in ascending order by `server_counts`, and then to `SELECT` only the first row (which is the minimum).

Comment: i dont have join_1 table it gives error  join_1 ' doesn't exist

Comment: @spencer7593 actually, the 'why isnt it working' was part of this question already - a point this answer fails to address